# WordPress database error Table 'uppampntvc.wpis_signups' doesn't exist

Tags: php, database, wordpress, apache, divi

I have a site built with Divi and LearnDash. I am receiving this error message in my logs and have no clue what it means. Any ideas?

[Wed Jan 13 14:24:30.583784 2021] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 16542:tid 139743547197184] [client 98.24.169.189:58558] AH01071: Got error 'PHP message: WordPress database error Table 'uppampntvc.wpis_signups' doesn't exist for query SELECT * FROM wpis_signups WHERE activation_key = '3h2yM0jrgK8RI4UwYgNs' made by require('wp-blog-header.php'), require_once('wp-includes/template-loader.php'), include('/themes/Divi/includes/builder/frontend-builder/theme-builder/frontend-body-template.php'), et_theme_builder_frontend_render_body, et_theme_builder_frontend_render_layout, et_builder_render_layout, apply_filters('et_builder_render_layout'), WP_Hook->apply_filters, do_shortcode, preg_replace_callback, do_shortcode_tag, ET_Builder_Element->_render, ET_Builder_Section->render, do_shortcode, preg_replace_callback, do_shortcode_tag, ET_Builder_Element->_render, ET_Builder_Row->render, do_shortcode, preg_replace_callback, do_shortcode_tag, ET_Builder_Element->_render, ET_Builder_Column->render, do_shortcode, preg_replace_callback, do_shortcode_tag, ET_Builder_Element->_render, ET_Builder_Module_Type_PostContent->render, et_theme_builder_frontend...'

Comment: Does this help? https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/162370/table-wp-signups-doesnt-exist

Answer (score 0):

Somehow you have deleted wordpress signups table. There is three way to solve this problem

1. Repair Wordpress:
   To repair it edit wp-config.php file and paste it at the top right after <?php tag

   define( 'WP_ALLOW_REPAIR', true );

Now visit your-site.com/wp-admin/maint/repair.php and follow the process.

2. Recreate database missing table:
   in this method you have to login phpmyadmin then create missing tables and columns manually. you will get default table and column names here: https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-admin/includes/schema.php

3. Delete everything and install fresh wordpress again.